# How to include database settings file?

Tags: php

My localhost location is on `c:\Web\www\..`

In `c:\web\www` I have all my pages

In `c:\web\scripts` I have all the scripts that import data from different sources

I know it would be best to move scripts to a web directory but for various reasons it is not possible

In the directory `c:\web\_include` I would like to create a file that I could include it in all pages and scripts

I have tried with

```
require ('//web1d01d/web/www/_include/setup_db.php');
```

('web1d01d' - it's my sever)

But it freezes the server (ability to view pages)

In the scripts directory, there are about 20 different scripts - run at different times.

file `setup_db.php` looks like this

```
<?php

class User {

    public function oracle() {
        return (object) array(
            'login'     => 'xxxxx',
            'passwd'    => 'xxxxx',
            'host'      => 'xxx.xxx.215.33:1521/yyyy',
            'hostspec'  => 'xxx.xxx.215.33',
            'port'      => '1521',
            'phptype'   => 'oci8',
            'service'   => 'yyyy'
        );
    }
    public function root() {
        return (object) array(
            'login'=>'root',
            'passwd'=>'xxxxx',
            'host'=>'web1d01d'
        );
    }

    public function odbc() {
        return (object) array(
            'login'=>'xxxxx',
            'passwd'=>'yyyyy',
            'host'=>'zzzzz'
        );
    }

};

?>
```

Perhaps this is because of `require`? Is this supposed to be used `require_once` instead of it?

Comment: Would the forward / rather than \ in the require be contributing?  It is better to set your include_path then call by include name as if you have several includes, the risk of typos increases...

Comment: try to use require_once(../_include/setup_db.php), so that when you will put all these files on another server , there is no need to change code for included files.

Comment: here is a hint: configuration should **not** be included again and again, and again, and again, and again ... ad nauseum.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code snippet.

```
$doc_root = rtrim ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], '/') . '/';

require_once($doc_root . '_include/setup_db.php');
```

Comment: This solution does not work for the scripts directory because ' $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ' points to the localhost location ' c:\web\www ' and scripts are not here

Comment: If so , then append 'scripts' after the $doc_root. You may try : `require_once($doc_root . 'scripts/_include/setup_db.php')`;

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); 
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__). DS .'..'. DS .'_include'. DS .'setup_db.php');
require_once $path;
```

Try this. Hope it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Aaaahh, i'm so stupid :D

I have use this

```
require_once('c:/web/www/_include/setup_db.php');
```

And it works perfect for scripts and for web pages... loool

Thank you guys for your help